# how do I delete test apps that I have uploaded to Quip

Tags: quip

I have created a few basic test apps and uploaded to my Quip A/c Since they are test apps and I wanted to see how the whole process works, I want to delete from my quip a/c so that I can work on some serious stuff.  How do I delete the test apps ?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove builds, but you can't delete an app right now. If the app was published by your admin, you will need them to unpublish it before removing a build.